# Adjust dynamic loaded content in td without new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After dynamic loading of data into TD of table, the values jumps to newline instead of increasing size of TD.

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <td style="width:250px">
  <div>
    <b>My Value is :</b>
    <span class="ass">0,00</span>
  </div>
  <i style="color:grey" class="fa fa-refresh"><span class="mo">Click refresh</span></i>
 </td>
  <td >
 <button value="Submit" class="button success " type="button" name="Management" id="Management">
  Refresh <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
  <button value="Submit" class="button success " type="button" name="Management1" id="Management1">
  Revert Back <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
 </button>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>

<span class="daal"></span>
```

Fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/3t6o1kor/

Is there any way in HTML/CSS not to create new line, but expand TD to adjust new text?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The changes are under testing. I will come by Monday with results on testing on other Servers. Even i could not test on local and i do not feel marking an answer based on working fiddles :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your td has fixed size. There are two solutions:

- You can change the td width to 350px, because the value doesn't fit in 250px.
- Another option is remove the width. In this case the td will increase the size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
 $(document).on('click', '#Management', function(e) {
   $(".ass").html("2132123242342342343213,00");
   $(".daal").html("See the new value jumps to new line. It should come in single line and do not create new line i.e td should expand automatically? Is there any way to do that in CSS or you can suggest other ways?");
   $(".mo").html("Click Revert Back");

   var my_b = $('#container_value').find('b').width();
   var my_span = $('#container_value').find('span').width();
   $('#container_value').width(my_b + my_span + 20);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '#Management1', function(e) {
 $('#container_value').css('width', 'initial');
   $(".ass").html("0,00");
   $(".daal").html("");
   $(".mo").html("Click Refresh");
 });
```

See here https://jsfiddle.net/3t6o1kor/1/

Answer (score 0):

removing the width has worked for me.